# Sequence contains no Element in c#

Tags: c#

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DataGridView dg = sender as DataGridView;
     if (dg != null && dg.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
     {
         DataGridViewRow row = dg.SelectedRows[0];
         if (row != null)
         {
             textBox1.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
             textBox2.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
             textBox3.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
             comboBox10.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
             dateTimePicker1.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();

             var buletinID = (int)row.Cells[15].Value;
             var dateBuletin = db.Buletin.Where(i => i.ID == buletinID + 1).First();
             textBox16.Text = dateBuletin.Seria.ToString();
             textBox17.Text = dateBuletin.Numarul.ToString();
             textBox18.Text = dateBuletin.Eliberat_de_oficiul.ToString();
             dateTimePicker3.Text = dateBuletin.Data_eliberarii.ToString();

             var livretID = (int)row.Cells[16].Value; 
             if (livretID != null)
             {

                 // This is the line that throws.
                 var dateLivret = db.Livret_militar.Where(i => i.ID == livretID).First(); 

                 textBox22.Text = dateLivret.Seria.ToString();
                 textBox23.Text = dateLivret.Numarul.ToString();
                 comboBox5.Text = dateLivret.Da_sau_Nu.ToString();
                 groupBox1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Where(c => c.Text == dateLivret.Evidenta.ToString()).FirstOrDefault().Checked = true;
             }
```

[image]

I use  a datagridview for show text in textboxes, combobox, datetimepicker, group of radio button. When i selected a row , text appear in empty boxes.

Comment: The collection is empty, that's why `First()` is throwing. Are you sure there are elements where `i.ID == livertID`?

Comment: Well, the message is pretty clear. `dateLivret` contains no element with an id equal to `livretID`.

Comment: id livret in databse = with null or some number

Comment: `if (livretID != null) {}` is obsolete. Int32 is a value type and cannot be null (and `0` is not `null`). If `row.Cells[16] ` is null and you try to parse it you'll get a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Also, you seem to be having some trouble with understanding the code - `(int)row.Cells[16].Value` will *never* be `null` - it's going to throw an exception if `row.Cells[16].Value` is `null` (or more likely, `DBNull.Value`). And seriously, *name your controls*. How can you work with names like `textBox16`? And again, finally you use `FirstOrDefault`, but then you `Checked = true` - but when the radio button is *not* found, this will cause a `NullReferenceException`. Understand the possible failure modes, and accomodate for them. Splashing `First`/`FirstOrDefault`/`!= null` around is not enough

Comment: I resolved this problem. I writte  incorect number for cell, thankyou for all